# Removing ChartJS 2 border and shadow from point style legend

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I am using the following option to get point style legend with ChartJS 2:

```
options: {
    legend: {
        labels: {
            usePointStyle: true
        }
    }
}
```

However, as displayed in the next image, each dot includes a border and a shadow:

[image]

ChartJS 2.7.2 is used.

Is there an option to control the border and the drop shadow? How can I remove them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the implementation, I noticed the border and shadow are controlled by the `borderWidth` property defined per dataset. Here is an example to remove the border and the shadow.

```
const dataset = [
    {
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: ...,
        label: ...,
        backgroundColor: ...,
        hoverBackgroundColor: ...,
    }
];
```

Note that the point diameter is linked to the label font size.

Answer (score 2):

As the borderWidth: 0 alone doesn't seem to work, a workaround is to set the borderColor with 0 opacity:

> ```
>   datasets: [
>     {
>       data: defaultData,
>       backgroundColor: colors,
>       borderWidth: 0,
>       borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", 
>     },
> ```